# problem with installing Network Storage drivers

Tags: macos, network, permission

i have a problem with accessing to my iomega-ix2 network storage. when i read the [manual](http://laurent.tomczyk.free.fr/serveur_bacprosen/doc_techniques/TR/storcenter_iomega_ix2/guide-utilisateur_ix2-200_fr.pdf), i found that i have to download and install certain files (download link is in the bottom)

so when i download the files and unzip them i found this:

```
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ ls -ltr
total 1236160
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff    8388608 Jun  7  2012 config
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 zImage.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff    2483788 Jun  7  2012 zImage
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 initrd.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff    2793059 Jun  7  2012 initrd
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff  619013120 Jun  7  2012 apps
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 oem.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff     208896 Jun  7  2012 oem
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 apps.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Apr 17  2013 config.md5
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$
```

so i tried to run *config* to configure the system for installation and that's what i have faced:

```
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ ./config
-bash: ./config: Permission denied
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ sudo chmod +x config
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ ls -ltr
total 1236160
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mrrm  staff    8388608 Jun  7  2012 config
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 zImage.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff    2483788 Jun  7  2012 zImage
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 initrd.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff    2793059 Jun  7  2012 initrd
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff  619013120 Jun  7  2012 apps
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 oem.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff     208896 Jun  7  2012 oem
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Jun  7  2012 apps.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 mrrm  staff         33 Apr 17  2013 config.md5
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ ./config
-bash: ./config: cannot execute binary file
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ chmod 575 config
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$ ./config
-bash: ./config: cannot execute binary file
imac-de-mr:files mrrm$
```

anyone knows what is the prolbem and how to solve it?

> i have a iMac 24-inch, **Late 2006** - Mac OS X Lion **10.7.5**

- [ix2-200-recovery-3.2.6.21659.zip](http://downloads.iomega.nas-central.org/Users/Mijzelf/ix2-200/ix2-200-recovery-3.2.6.21659.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I think you downloaded the firmware for the device.

Try [this link](https://lenovo-na-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26107) to the OS X download page for the IX2.

Or [this link](http://download.lenovo.com/nas/storagemanager/macosx/lsm_mac_pkg-1.4.6.33040.dmg) to directly download the dmg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems like you gave me a link fo the wrong device, i tied [this](https://lenovo-na-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/21686/related/1) one, it's in the same website and it works

Comment: booth of them did not work! any ideas?